# how to model a grid data type?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, vector

How can I model a grid(minesweeper problem) as a data type in the best possible way? Is it better to use a vector as 2 dimensional entity. The reason for a vector is because of its bounds checking capabilities. Is my assumption right?

Thanks :)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that operator[] on std::vector does not do range checking as this would incur a performance penalty. Some compiler allow you to transparently insert range checking. Such as G++ does when you define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG. For more info see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt12ch30s04.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the grid-size is (I presume!) fixed, a vector gives you little advantage over an array. So I recommend going with a 2D array.

While not necessary, you might find it useful to add [sentinel values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) around the boundary of the grid to remove the need for implicit bounds checking. An example is placing 0's all around the grid for when you're summing the number of neighbouring mines. Read [this article](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=features&d2=090104) for some simpler examples to begin with.

Comment: A vector can take its size at runtime. For an array to take its size at runtime you need to manage memory on your own. So no, there **is** an advantage for using a vector here.

Comment: @wilhelmtell I consider that little advantage, but that's personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that the vest option is to use a specialized class that acts like a multidimensional array while giving you the benefits of the STL vector (size-aware, no implicit conversions to pointers, etc.). Boost's multi_array class might be a good candidate here, and more generally whenever you need a multidimensional array.  It handles all of the weirdness normally associated with raw C++ arrays without sacrificing performance.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have a large grid which is mostly empty you could use a std::map keyed with a std::pair. You would **only use this approach if you are more concerned about memory than time** taken to access the elements. As the memory would be linear in the number of non-empty cells O(n) and access would be O(log n) where using a matrix would be O(mp) in memory (where m and p are your matrix dimensions) and O(1) to access.

Comment: I'm really just a beginner. Maybe memory management will be helpful for future puzzles. But thanks for input :)